# Bulletproof @Font-Face syntax subtleties

Tags: css, fonts, sass, less, frontend

I'm sorry for the mistakes I've made, I'm not Englishman. I want to find out the difference between these two examples:

```
//generated by icomoon.io
@font-face {
  font-family: icomoon;
  src:url('font.eot?-w9xgwa');
  src:url('font.eot?#iefix-w9xgwa') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('font.woff?-w9xgwa') format('woff'),
  url('font.ttf?-w9xgwa') format('truetype'),
  url('font.svg?-w9xgwa#icomoon') format('svg');
}

//generated by my Sass mixin
@font-face {
  font-family: icomoon;
  src: url('font.eot');
  src: url('font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('font.woff') format('woff'),
  url('font.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('font.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
}
```

Both examples work and icons are rendered correctly, but I have some doubts about parameters which are appended at the end of each font's url (eg: `font.ext?-blabla` or `font.ext#blabla`). What do they mean?

Do I make mistake when I use incorrect parameters at the end of the url?
The reason of asking question: I want to make SASS mixin, that help me easily include custom fonts generated by different resources (icomoon.io, fontello.com etc).

Comment: There are many website explaining the purposes and workings of the "bulletproof" system. http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/ for instance. And yes, there are several such schemes; if these two both work in all browsers, take your pick!

Comment: And as for not being an Englishman, that's all right. There are few Englishmen on this site! (On average, they have very high reputations though.)

Comment: Sorry guy, but this article absolutely useless for me, because it doesn't give me any explanation about parameters at the end of url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Icomoon appends query string parameters (everything after the `?`, in this case `-w9xgwa`), to either distinguish the font you were served from others generated, or more likely, to break the cache when your font is updated. Your font when served to users is likely cached (so they don't have to download it each time they view your page). Appending the query string, and changing it will cause the user agent to download it again.

I would recommend hard-coding the css generated by icomoon, and changing it when you update the font. If you don't plan on ever changing it (or needing to break the cache of a user viewing your font), then your probably fine using the mixin generated version.

Comment: Great! Is it work for including css? For example: <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css?version_0.1"/>

Comment: Yes, that works too. If you remember to change the random string every time you change the stylesheet.